# Unexpected SEGFAULT when there's apparently nothing that would cause it

Tags: assembly, linux

This is a from a CTF problem I'm working on. Hopefully it's appropriate to ask this question here.

[image: GDB output when segmentation fault happens]

Above is the GDB output when the segfault goes off. `movaps` is the offending instruction, meaning that `rsp+0x40` is most likely pointing to unmapped memory.

However, a closer look at the memory allocated for the stack

[image: stack memory map]

and `rsp=0x00007ffde19d78a8` from the GDB output, shows that `rsp+0x40` is well within the allocated bounds. This is really confusing for me, is there something I'm missing here? Something else I can look into to debug this?

Finally the output when running this under `strace`

```
[pid 32671] --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_addr=NULL} ---
[pid 32671] +++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
```

shows that it's apparently a null pointer dereference (`si_addr=NULL`), which doesn't make any sense to me because the offending instruction `movaps XMMWORD PTR [rsp+0x40],xmm0` isn't accessing a NULL pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_180.html) the address should be aligned by 16, which is not happen. Your `rsp` value is ending by `0xa8`, so `[rsp + 0x40]` will be aligned by 8, not 16.

Comment: Should've read that 2nd paragraph! Thanks a lot, actually had no idea misalignment could trigger hardware faults, always thought it was *just* less efficient.